# Difference between GridPane.add and GridPane.setContraint

Tags: java, javafx

I am reading some tutorials about JavaFX 2.0 and I am a bit confused about two methods of the GridPane layout component.

Basically, I would add a node to a GridPane using GridPane.add(new Label("My Label"), 0, 0);

However, I have seen the following methods used too: GridPane.setContraint(new Label("My Label"), 0, 0);

Can anyone explain me the difference between these two methods?
I had a look to the javadoc, but could not get the difference, maybe my English is not good enough to get slight difference?

Thank you in advance.

Clem

Answer (score 1):

I have done some more testing and found out that .setContraints(node, column, row) does not actually add the node the GridPane's children and you will have to add them manually afterwards, whereas .add(node, column, row) do actually set the column and row indexes and also add the node to the GridPane's children.